# How can I get ChangeResourceRecordSetsNormalizedRecordNames Route53 permission working through Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-iam, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-route53

I'm trying to limit permissions through Terraform on Route53. I want my environment to be able to make changes to record sets only in its specific hosted zone, and to it's own domain.

I can't seem to get the ChangeResourceRecordSetsNormalizedRecordNames working. Anything online just seems to show the json and I need the terraform code specifically. Has anyone managed to achieve this?

I'm trying to achieve the following through terraform:

```json
 "Effect": "Allow"
 "Action": "route53:ChangeResourceRecordSets",
 "Resource": "arn:aws:route53:::hostedzone/xxxxxxx",
 "Condition": {
    "ForAllValues:StringLike":{
      "route53:ChangeResourceRecordSetsNormalizedRecordNames": ["service-*.{domain_name}"]
```

I've tried every variation of the following that I can think of:

```
    statement {
      sid    = "AllowRoute53"
      effect = "Allow"
      actions = [
        "route53:ChangeResourceRecordSets"
      ]
      resources = ["arn:aws:route53:::hostedzone/${data.aws_route_53.zone_id.value}"]

      condition {
        test     = "ForAnyValue:StringLike"
        variable = "route53:ChangeResourceRecordSetsNormalizedRecordNames"
        values   = [${data.domain_name}]
    }
```

Comment: Well, the JSON example says `ForAllValues:StringLike` and your example is with `ForAnyValues:StringLike`. Furthermore, it's unclear what `data.domain_name` is.

Comment: I've tried both ForAll and ForAny and still nothing. I'm unsure of what I should be putting in the values field here. I'll take anything that can get the ChangeResourceRecordSetsNormalizedRecordNames working at this stage, and work from there.

Comment: I'm confused. Should the JSON example provide what you need or not?

Comment: Yes, the JSON should provide what I need but I'm unsure of how to achieve the same thing through Terraform, without the use of JSON, if that makes sense.

Comment: Most of it looks correct, except for this part `values   = [${data.domain_name}]`. Can you add what `data.domain_name` is supposed to represent?

Comment: Think I managed to get it with the following. Thanks!

 `statement {

    sid    = "AllowRoute53"
    effect = "Allow"
    actions = [
      "route53:ChangeResourceRecordSets"
    ]
    resources = ["arn:aws:route53:::hostedzone/${var.hosted_zone_id}"]
    condition {
      test     = "StringLike"
      values   = ["${var.domain_name}"]
      variable = "route53:ChangeResourceRecordSetsNormalizedRecordNames"
    }
  }`

Comment: @AdamE Please reply to your own question with the actual (formatted) code. Reading it from the comment is unpracticalt at least.